# Request body or query param with numbers greater than 10 digits showing 404 error in Tomcat 8.5 and Spring Boot 2.2 setup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

We are running our spring boot application on AWS tomcat server 8.5, whenever the request or query param contains a Long data type such as 4343434567654 which is greater than 10 digits the request does not even hit the filter code. I tried the following solutions to verify the issue

Here is my filter to log the request and response data

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

 @Override
 public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new 
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new 
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper(
            (HttpServletResponse) response);

    try {
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
    } finally {

        String requestBody = new 
        String(requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        String responseBody = new 
        String(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        System.out.println("requestBody :" + requestBody);
        System.out.println("responseBody :" + responseBody);
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();

    }

}

}
```

My Controller Code is

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @PostMapping("/postdata")
    public Body postDate(@RequestBody Body body) {
        return body;
    }

}
```

Bean Class

```
public class Body {
    private Long commentId;

    public Long getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    public void setCommentId(Long commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }
}
```

code to handle 404 error is below

```
@PostMapping(value = "/*")
public ResponseEntity<ErrorRes> getNotFoundHandler() {
        ErrorRes error = new ErrorRes();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
        error.setErrorDescription(request.getRequestURI());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

The request in postman is as below

[image]

I tried running the same in my local environment with the same apache tomcat version and higher versions, I tried running the application as jar and deploy it in the same machine and the issue was not there. only with this specific tomcat instance, the issues seem to be present.
Also i tried changing the

```
@Requestbody Body body to @Requestbody String body
```

and the issue is still there
Is there any configuration to allow Long data type in request body or query param?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, we are running Prevoty RASP in our tomcat server which was unable to parse JSON with Long data type it was trying to convert Long to Integer which caused number format exception therefore the request was not even allowed inside the dispatcher servlet, seems this is a bug with RAPS 3.x version. Upgrading to latest version fixed this issue.